¿Cómo puedo calcular el IVA de un producto, dependiendo si tiene IVA o no tiene IVA con JavaScript?
Total e IVA de un producto, considerando si el producto tiene o no tiene IVA.
¡Hola, a tod@s!
Estoy intentando encontrar la solución a lo siguiente: Necesito sacar el Total de un producto, teniendo en cuenta si éste tiene o no tiene IVA.
Si tiene IVA, calcularlo con el 16% seleccionándolo desde el checkbox, si no tiene IVA, que la cantidad que ingreso en Monto, se vaya directo al Total.

Agrego el código:


  function calculo(){
  //tasa de impuesto
    var tasa = 16;

  //monto a calcular el impuesto
    var monto = $("input[name=monto]").val();

  //calsulo del impuesto
    var iva = (monto * tasa)/100;

  //se carga el iva en el campo correspondien te
    $("input[name=iva]").val(iva);

  //se carga el total en el campo correspondiente
    $("input[name=total]").val(parseInt(monto)+parseInt(iva));
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>prueba</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <table id="items">

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="alert alert-info">
      <p>
        Muestra de Calculo de Iva
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
       <DIV clas="col-md-12">

         <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
           <div clsss="form-group">
             <input type="text" name="monto" class="form-control" placeholder="Monto" onChange="calculo();">
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
           <div clsss="form-group">
             <input type="text" name="iva" class="form-control" placeholder="IVA" readonly>
             <select name="IVA" type="text" required>
              <option value="0">0</option>
              <option value="16">16</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
         <div clsss="form-group">
           <input type="text" name="total" class="form-control" placeholder="Total" readonly>
         </div>
       </div>
     </DIV>
   </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>




¿Qué te detiene para calcular el IVA en base al monto que está en el select? En esa función estás diciendo que siempre el valor del IVA es de 16.

Hola Hugo, así como obtenes el monto, podes obtener la tasa, es más de lo mismo.

Hola, @padaleiana. Gracias por tu respuesta, estoy tratando de encontrar la solución sobre cómo puedo calcular el iva desde el select. Si tiene IVA seleccionar el 16, si no tiene IVA seleccionar el 0.

Hola, @Marcos. Gracias por tu respuesta, no es muy claro lo que me sugieres hacer.

Lo que sugirió @Marcos es bastante claro, de hecho. Tanto en JS como en jQuery (lo que estás utilizando), harás bastante uso de los selectores.

Por cierto, la idea es enseñarte a pescar, no a darte el pez... Lee [ask].

¡Claro!, lo entiendo. Gracias, @padaleiana.

Gracias a sus sugerencias, pude resolver mi pregunta.

Si he entendido bien tu pregunta, puedes intentar lo siguiente:


  function calculo(){
  //tasa de impuesto
    var tasa = $("#selectIva").val();

  //monto a calcular el impuesto
    var monto = $("input[name=monto]").val();

  //calsulo del impuesto
    var iva = 0;
    if(tasa != 0){
     iva= (monto * tasa)/100;
    }
    

  //se carga el iva en el campo correspondien te
    $("input[name=iva]").val(iva);

  //se carga el total en el campo correspondiente
    $("input[name=total]").val(parseInt(monto)+parseInt(iva));
}

$('select').on('change', function() {
  calculo();
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alert alert-info">
      <p>
        Muestra de Calculo de Iva
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
       <DIV clas="col-md-12">

         <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
           <div clsss="form-group">
             <input type="text" name="monto" class="form-control" placeholder="Monto" onChange="calculo();">
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
           <div clsss="form-group">
             <input type="text" name="iva" class="form-control" placeholder="IVA" readonly>
             <select id="selectIva" type="text" required>
              <option value="0">0</option>
              <option value="16">16</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
         <div clsss="form-group">
           <input type="text" name="total" class="form-control" placeholder="Total" readonly>
         </div>
       </div>
     </DIV>
   </div>
 </div>




¿Qué es "lo siguiente"? Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer]. No te limites a explicar brevemente a través de comentarios de código.

Las publicaciones que son básicamente código sin explicación de qué hacen o cómo solucionan el problema se consideran de baja calidad ya que no suelen ser de ayuda para otros usuarios que pueden no entender lo que se hizo. Considera editar tu respuesta y añadir más detalles.

Gracias por la sugerencia, @padaleiana.
